# How do you texture map a plane on WebGL?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have created a basic scene consisting of a floor(plane), table, and a cube. I now want to move onto texturing the floor with a wooden texture image [Click to see the wooden texture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eObZX.jpg) I know very little about texturing and fairly new to WebGL.

I have some idea of having to load the image from my directory, but not sure on how to apply it to the floor. In addition to this, I am unsure on the texture vertex coordinates needed for the plane(floor).

I am also aware I will need to add new attributes to allow texturing. Would you need to change the overall layout of the object for the texture to take place?

Would appreciate any advice on where to start and how I can go about this task.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Drawing In 3D </title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="glMatrix.js"></script>
        <script src="webgl-debug.js"></script>
        <script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
            attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
            attribute vec4 aVertexColor;
            uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
            uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
            varying vec4 vColor;
            void main() {
                gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
                vColor = aVertexColor;
            }
        </script>
    
        <script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
          precision mediump float;
          varying vec4 vColor;
          void main() {
                            gl_FragColor = vColor;
                        }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var gl;
            var canvas;
            var shaderProgram;
            var floorVertexPositionBuffer;
            var floorVertexIndexBuffer;
            var cubeVertexPositionBuffer;
            var cubeVertexIndexBuffer;
            var modelViewMatrix;
            var projectionMatrix;
            var modelViewMatrixStack;
    
            function createGLContext(canvas) {
                var names = ["webgl", "experimental-webgl"];
                var context = null;
                for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                    try {
                        context = canvas.getContext(names[i]);
                    } catch (e) { }
                    if (context) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (context) {
                    context.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
                    context.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
                } else {
                    alert("Failed to create WebGL context!");
                }
                return context;
            }
    
            function loadShaderFromDOM(id) {
                var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);
                if (!shaderScript) {
                    return null;
                }
                var shaderSource = "";
                var currentChild = shaderScript.firstChild;
                while (currentChild) {
                    if (currentChild.nodeType == 3) { // 3 corresponds to TEXT_NODE
                        shaderSource += currentChild.textContent;
                    }
                    currentChild = currentChild.nextSibling;
                }
    
                var shader;
                if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
                    shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
                } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
                    shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
    
                gl.shaderSource(shader, shaderSource);
                gl.compileShader(shader);
    
                if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
                    alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
                    return null;
                }
                return shader;
            }
    
            function setupShaders() {
                var vertexShader = loadShaderFromDOM("shader-vs");
                var fragmentShader = loadShaderFromDOM("shader-fs");
                shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
                gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
                gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
                gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);
    
                if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
                    alert("Failed to setup shaders");
                }
    
                gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);
                shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
                shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexColor");
                shaderProgram.uniformMVMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");
                shaderProgram.uniformProjMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
    
                // Initialise the matrices
                modelViewMatrix = mat4.create();
                projectionMatrix = mat4.create();
                modelViewMatrixStack = [];
                gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);
            }
    
            function pushModelViewMatrix() {
                var copyToPush = mat4.create(modelViewMatrix);
                modelViewMatrixStack.push(copyToPush);
            }
    
            function popModelViewMatrix() {
                if (modelViewMatrixStack.length == 0) {
                    throw "Error popModelViewMatrix() - Stack was empty ";
                }
                modelViewMatrix = modelViewMatrixStack.pop();
            }
    
            function setupFloorBuffers() {
                floorVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, floorVertexPositionBuffer);
    
                var floorVertexPosition = [
                    // Plane in y=0
                    5.0, 0.0, 5.0,  //v0
                    5.0, 0.0, -5.0,  //v1
                    -5.0, 0.0, -5.0,  //v2
                    -5.0, 0.0, 5.0]; //v3
    
                gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(floorVertexPosition), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
                floorVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
                floorVertexPositionBuffer.numberOfItems = 4;
                floorVertexIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, floorVertexIndexBuffer);
                var floorVertexIndices = [0, 1, 2, 3];
                gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(floorVertexIndices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
                floorVertexIndexBuffer.itemSize = 1;
                floorVertexIndexBuffer.numberOfItems = 4;
            }
    
            function setupCubeBuffers() {
                cubeVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexPositionBuffer);
    
                var cubeVertexPosition = [
                    1.0, 1.0, 1.0, //v0
                    -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, //v1
                    -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, //v2
                    1.0, -1.0, 1.0, //v3
                    1.0, 1.0, -1.0, //v4
                    -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, //v5
                    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, //v6
                    1.0, -1.0, -1.0, //v7
                ];
    
                gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(cubeVertexPosition), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
                cubeVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
                cubeVertexPositionBuffer.numberOfItems = 8;
                cubeVertexIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexIndexBuffer);
    
                var cubeVertexIndices = [
                    0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3,    // Front face
                    4, 6, 5, 4, 7, 6,    // Back face
                    1, 5, 6, 1, 6, 2, //left
                    0, 3, 7, 0, 7, 4, //right
                    0, 5, 1, 0, 4, 5, //top
                    3, 2, 6, 3, 6, 7  //bottom
                ];
    
                gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(cubeVertexIndices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
                cubeVertexIndexBuffer.itemSize = 1;
                cubeVertexIndexBuffer.numberOfItems = 36;
            }
    
            function setupBuffers() {
                setupFloorBuffers();
                setupCubeBuffers();
            }
    
            function uploadModelViewMatrixToShader() {
                gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.uniformMVMatrix, false, modelViewMatrix);
            }
    
            function uploadProjectionMatrixToShader() {
                gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.uniformProjMatrix, false, projectionMatrix);
            }
    
            function drawFloor(r, g, b, a) {
    
                // Disable vertex attrib array and use constant color for the floor.
                gl.disableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute);
    
                // Set colour
                gl.vertexAttrib4f(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute, r, g, b, a);
    
                // Draw the floor
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, floorVertexPositionBuffer);
                gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, floorVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, floorVertexIndexBuffer);
                gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, floorVertexIndexBuffer.numberOfItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
            }
    
            function drawCube(r, g, b, a) {
    
                // Disable vertex attrib array and use constant color for the cube.
                gl.disableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute);
    
                // Set color
                gl.vertexAttrib4f(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute, r, g, b, a);
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexPositionBuffer);
                gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, cubeVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexIndexBuffer);
                gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, cubeVertexIndexBuffer.numberOfItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
            }
    
            function drawTable() {
    
                // Draw table top
                pushModelViewMatrix();
                mat4.translate(modelViewMatrix, [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], modelViewMatrix);
                mat4.scale(modelViewMatrix, [2.0, 0.1, 2.0], modelViewMatrix);
                uploadModelViewMatrixToShader();
    
                // Draw the scaled cube
                drawCube(0.72, 0.53, 0.04, 1.0); // brown color
                popModelViewMatrix();
    
                // Draw table legs
                for (var i = -1; i <= 1; i += 2) {
                    for (var j = -1; j <= 1; j += 2) {
                        pushModelViewMatrix();
                        mat4.translate(modelViewMatrix, [i * 1.9, -0.1, j * 1.9], modelViewMatrix);
                        mat4.scale(modelViewMatrix, [0.1, 1.0, 0.1], modelViewMatrix);
                        uploadModelViewMatrixToShader();
                        drawCube(0.72, 0.53, 0.04, 1.0); // argument sets brown color
                        popModelViewMatrix();
                    }
                }
            }
    
            function draw() {
                gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
                gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                mat4.perspective(60, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0, projectionMatrix);
                mat4.identity(modelViewMatrix);
                mat4.lookAt([8, 5, -10], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], modelViewMatrix);
                uploadModelViewMatrixToShader();
                uploadProjectionMatrixToShader();
    
                // Draw floor in red color
                drawFloor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    
                // Draw table
                pushModelViewMatrix();
                mat4.translate(modelViewMatrix, [0.0, 1.1, 0.0], modelViewMatrix);
                uploadModelViewMatrixToShader();
                drawTable(); //Call drawTable() function
                popModelViewMatrix();
    
                // Draw box on top of the table
                pushModelViewMatrix();
                mat4.translate(modelViewMatrix, [0.0, 2.7, 0.0], modelViewMatrix);
                mat4.scale(modelViewMatrix, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5], modelViewMatrix);
                uploadModelViewMatrixToShader();
                drawCube(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
                popModelViewMatrix()
    
            }
    
            function startup() {
                canvas = document.getElementById("myGLCanvas");
                gl = WebGLDebugUtils.makeDebugContext(createGLContext(canvas));
                setupShaders();
                setupBuffers();
                gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
                gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
                draw();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="startup();">
        <canvas id="myGLCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're asking something that is a fairly large topic. First off you need to know how to use [texture coordinates and how to load images](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-textures.html). To use images from a different website you need to know about [CORS permissions](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-cors-permission.html). You also need to know what you probably need to [run a simple web server](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-setup-and-installation.html) otherwise WebGL will not be able to load the images.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `loadTexture()` method to load textures in WebGL project.

> The loadTexture() routine starts by creating a WebGL texture object
>   texture by calling the WebGL createTexture() function. It then uploads
>   a single blue pixel using texImage2D(). This makes the texture
>   immediately usable as a solid blue color even though it may take a few
>   moments for our image to download.
>
> To load the texture from the image file, it then creates an Image
>   object and assigned the src to the URL for our image we wish to use as
>   our texture. The function we assign to image.onload will be called
>   once the image has finished downloading. At that point, we again call
>   texImage2D() this time using the image as the source of the texture.
>   After that we setup filtering and wrapping for the texture based on
>   whether or not the image we download was a power of 2 in both
>   dimensions or not.

```
function loadTexture(gl, url) {
  const texture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

  // Because images have to be download over the internet
  // they might take a moment until they are ready.
  // Until then put a single pixel in the texture so we can
  // use it immediately. When the image has finished downloading
  // we'll update the texture with the contents of the image.
  const level = 0;
  const internalFormat = gl.RGBA;
  const width = 1;
  const height = 1;
  const border = 0;
  const srcFormat = gl.RGBA;
  const srcType = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
  const pixel = new Uint8Array([0, 0, 255, 255]);  // opaque blue
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat,
                width, height, border, srcFormat, srcType,
                pixel);

  const image = new Image();
  image.onload = function() {
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat,
                  srcFormat, srcType, image);

    // WebGL1 has different requirements for power of 2 images
    // vs non power of 2 images so check if the image is a
    // power of 2 in both dimensions.
    if (isPowerOf2(image.width) && isPowerOf2(image.height)) {
       // Yes, it's a power of 2. Generate mips.
       gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
    } else {
       // No, it's not a power of 2. Turn of mips and set
       // wrapping to clamp to edge
       gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
       gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
       gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    }
  };
  image.src = url;

  return texture;
}
```

Or have a look at this [cube with texture WebGL tutorial](https://gist.github.com/elnaqah/5070979) on git hub.